# Finding max value from list and assigning it to explode value in Pie chart MatPlotLib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

[Exploded Pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaUf7.png)

I am working in matplotlib.pyplot and still learning.  I want to explode the largest value in the pie chart.  Instead of hard coding the values in `explode_values`, is there a way to find max value from `y_axis` list and assign correlating `explode_value` while assigning the rest to zero, which would eliminate having to hard code the `explode_values`?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_axis = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
# Set the y-axis to a list of floats as the total fare in US dollars accumulated for each month.
y_axis = [10.02, 23.24, 39.20, 35.42, 32.34, 27.04, 43.82, 10.56, 11.85, 27.90, 20.71, 20.09]

fig, ax =plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
colors = ["slateblue", "magenta", "lightblue", "green", "yellowgreen", "greenyellow", "yellow", "orange", "gold", "indianred", "tomato", "mistyrose"]
explode_values = (0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
ax.pie(y_axis, labels=x_axis,
    autopct='%.1f%%',
    shadow=True,
    startangle=270.0,
    colors=colors,
    explode=explode_values)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

Comment: As y_axis in your code is a list, you can use max(y_axis) to find the maximum value in the list. But how do you generating the explode value? please clarify

Comment: Is there a way to use a for loop to set the values in explode_values to 0 unless it equals the max(y_axis) index, and set that one to 0.2?

Comment: please check the solution posted below and let me know if I can further help you

Comment: Yes!  Both solutions worked.  Thank you.  Now to understand how it is done.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
y_axis = [10.02, 23.24, 39.20, 35.42, 32.34, 27.04, 43.82, 10.56, 11.85, 27.90, 20.71, 20.09]
max_val = max(y_axis)
max_index = y_axis.index(max_val)
explode_value = tuple([0 if i!=max_index else 0.2 for i in range(len(y_axis))])
print(explode_value)
```

Output:
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

However, if you want to set the explode value **depending on y_axis** value and keep the explode value **in range 0 to 1**, try the following code

```
x_axis = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
y_axis = [10.02, 23.24, 39.20, 35.42, 32.34, 27.04, 43.82, 10.56, 11.85, 27.90, 20.71, 20.09]
max_val = max(y_axis)
max_index = y_axis.index(max_val)
explode_value = tuple([0 if i!=max_index else round((max_val/sum(y_axis)),2) for i in range(len(y_axis))])
print(explode_value)
```

Again, if you want to set the explode value **depending on y_axis** value and in **percentage**, try the following code

```
x_axis = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
y_axis = [10.02, 23.24, 39.20, 35.42, 32.34, 27.04, 43.82, 10.56, 11.85, 27.90, 20.71, 20.09]
max_val = max(y_axis)
max_index = y_axis.index(max_val)
explode_value = tuple([0 if i!=max_index else round((max_val/sum(y_axis)),2)*100 for i in range(len(y_axis))])
print(explode_value)
```